# ps-ef|grep pmon (Instance Name Only)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, oracle-12c, oracle-10g

When i issue a "ps -ef|grep pmon", I get the below output.

```
oracle   230330      1  0 Jan08 ?        00:01:14 asm_pmon_+ASM1      
oracle   244018      1  0 Jan08 ?        00:00:59 ora_pmon_vbsenopd     
oracle   244020      1  0 Jan08 ?        00:01:01 ora_pmon_vbdrazpd      
oracle   244021      1  0 Jan08 ?        00:01:00 ora_pmon_vbrmant      
oracle   244042      1  0 Jan08 ?        00:01:25 ora_pmon_dx07123      
oracle   244080      1  0 Jan08 ?        00:01:28 ora_pmon_rpasnap1
```

Now, Is there anyway that i can get only the active database names (for eg. rpasnap1 instead of ora_pmon_rpasnap1) using "ps-ef|grep pmon" or any other method?

**Your help is my salvation.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep
oracle   23955     1  0 Jan16 ?        00:00:33 asm_pmon_+ASM
oracle   27366     1  0 Jan16 ?        00:00:31 ora_pmon_S112

$ ps -ef | grep pmon | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $8 }' | cut -d '_' -f3
+ASM
S112

$ ps -e -o command | grep pmon | grep -v grep | cut -d '_' -f3
+ASM
S112
```

Comment: :-) Now thats whats the doctor ordered. Thank you.